# JMeter can JSON path assertion plugin match to an array?

Tags: json, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

In one of my tests I need to check that the data in an array matches to an expected result.
I send an API call and receive the following JSON response:

```
{
"sting": "value",
"another string": "value",
"array": ["value1","value2","value3"]
}
```

Using the JSON Path Assertion plugin I'm able to check each value individually.

```
$.array[0]
```

Is there a way to evaluate all the array's values in one assertion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking into [Can't check an array with JSONPath Assertion. Update JSONPath to 2.1?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/jmeter-plugins/JSONPath$20Assertion/jmeter-plugins/MUQ0SnPqDy4/r4sZGTmkAwAJ) currently it is not possible.

You can work it around using [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) instead as follows:

1. Add JSON Path Extractor as a child of the request which returns above JSON and configure it as follows:

   - Destination Variable Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `array`
   - JSON Path Expression: `$.array`
2. Add Response Assertion **after** the JSON Path Extractor and configure it as follows:

   - Apply to -> JMeter Variable -> `array`
   - Pattern Matching Rules: `Equals`
   - Patterns to Test: `["value1","value2","value3"]` - make sure there are no trailing spaces, new lines, etc.

     [image: Response Assertion]

Example Test Plan:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="2.8" jmeter="2.13 r1665067">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Test Plan" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <longProp name="ThreadGroup.start_time">1456157004000</longProp>
        <longProp name="ThreadGroup.end_time">1456157004000</longProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler guiclass="kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySamplerGui" testclass="kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler" testname="jp@gc - Dummy Sampler" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="WAITING">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="SUCCESFULL">true</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="RESPONSE_CODE">200</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="RESPONSE_MESSAGE">OK</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="REQUEST_DATA">Dummy Sampler used to simulate requests and responses
without actual network activity. This helps debugging tests.</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="RESPONSE_DATA">{
&quot;sting&quot;: &quot;value&quot;,
&quot;another string&quot;: &quot;value&quot;,
&quot;array&quot;: [&quot;value1&quot;,&quot;value2&quot;,&quot;value3&quot;]
}</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="RESPONSE_TIME">${__Random(50,500)}</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="LATENCY">${__Random(1,50)}</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="CONNECT">${__Random(1,5)}</stringProp>
        </kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler>
        <hashTree>
          <com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor guiclass="com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.gui.JSONPathExtractorGui" testclass="com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor" testname="jp@gc - JSON Path Extractor" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="VAR">array</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="JSONPATH">$.array</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="DEFAULT"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="VARIABLE"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="SUBJECT">BODY</stringProp>
          </com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor>
          <hashTree/>
          <ResponseAssertion guiclass="AssertionGui" testclass="ResponseAssertion" testname="Response Assertion" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="Asserion.test_strings">
              <stringProp name="-1728402013">[&quot;value1&quot;,&quot;value2&quot;,&quot;value3&quot;]</stringProp>
            </collectionProp>
            <stringProp name="Assertion.test_field">Assertion.response_data</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="Assertion.assume_success">false</boolProp>
            <intProp name="Assertion.test_type">8</intProp>
            <stringProp name="Assertion.scope">variable</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Scope.variable">array</stringProp>
          </ResponseAssertion>
          <hashTree/>
        </hashTree>
      </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

If your response may vary, i.e. array members order changes, you might need to consider scripting-based assertion, i.e. [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) instead

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) guide for comprehensive information on using JMeter Assertions in your tests.

Comment: This doesn't work. When I run the test I receive the following error: Test failed: variable(array) expected to match /["value1","value2","value3"]/ @Dmitri T

Comment: Yes you are correct. However the first sentence in your comment was unnecessary. @Dmitri T

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work by using the `..` syntax. In your case, it would be `$..array` which would return

```
[
    "value1",
    "value2",
    "value3"
]
```

Then you could, for example, check the "additionally assert value" box and "match as regular expression" and then do `\w+` as the expected value, asserting that there is a word there.